# How does the Flash/AS3 player read the length of mp3 files?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, mp3

I have an AS3 music player built into an app that I'm putting together.  It works perfectly with almost every file I've used, but there is one file that it stops early on.  The file is roughly 56 seconds long, the player stops at about 44 seconds.  I'm using trace to show the length, and for every other song the length is correct.  In this case, trace shows roughly 44 seconds instead of 56.  Here's the code I use to load the file:

```
length = 0;
request = new URLRequest(fileAddress);
track = new Sound();
track.load(request);
track.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, TrackLoaded);
```

And here's the TrackLoaded function:

```
private function TrackLoaded(e:Event):void{
  length = track.length;
  if (playWhenLoaded == true){
    trackChannel = track.play(0);
    trackChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, TrackFinishedPlaying);
    playWhenLoaded = false;
  }
```

Works perfectly with every other file.  What am I missing?

Comment: Never heard of that, but these guys say that it's normal (not sure, worth trying): http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?332063-Incorrect-sound-length-property-value

Comment: Ah, I was worried about that.  This is running in an application, will have to see what we can do to get the lengths ironed out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to host this 56 sec MP3 somewhere for download & analysis? Or if you can yourself check the header info via a Hexeditor. I suspect either of two things:

1) Header has incorrect time length embedded and Flash takes that as final duration and stops there. After all why read anymore remaining bytes? they could be just metadata not audio samples Besides what encoder would lie about true duration? So its accepted as final duration even if your ears know that its incorrect.

2) MP3 samplerate /bitrate issue: Consider what sample rate is this one problem MP3? Check the sample rate against of a working MP3. Also are these various found sounds or you made each yourself? I ask to confirm you put the same settings for each file yet this one does not work?

In anycase I think you could solve this particular MP3 by re-encoding it. Maybe save as WAV or AIFF first then take that new uncompressed audio and convert back to a MP3 with samplerate of 44100 khz + Stereo sound + Constant Bitrate (avoid Variable B.Rate like hell if you dont want issues)

Checking and fixing either of the above should get you are correctly parsed MP3. Hope it helps

Comment: Take a look at http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?332063-Incorrect-sound-length-property-value.  I haven't checked the headers, but every other program plays it correctly- Blaze Audio's RipEditBurn Plus, Windows Media Player, Audacity.  This seems to be an AS3 problem.

Comment: Indeed, But since you say Flash is fine with all others except this one file you have to deduce what's "special" about it compared to the others. Flash prefers 44100 khz 2-channel sound as best input (CD Quality). Consider `Sound.load()` decodes audio formats to 44100 uncompressed PCM anyway with a 128kb bitrate from my experiences. Anyway I've seen the Kirupa link. No offense but I dont see its value except that "...Wait until sound end for correct time". What will PHP do for you? You'll get a number but Flash still stops at 44s. Re-encoding with a freeware program will help fix this 99.99%.

Comment: If you can share the file size in `.totalbytes` and also the bit rate and sample rate I could try and work out where this 44 secs VS 56 secs is coming from. It's cool if you can't show the file (W-I-P restrictions et al) but it would have made diagnosis easier.

Comment: Please take a look at the link that Andrey Popov provided in his comment to my original question. My question was how AS3 did it, obviously it doesn't do it the right way. Apparently there is a problem with AS3 that other programs do not have. This program will need to play many different music files.  Yes, I understand that I will probably end up having to read the headers.